# Should I wrap an angular site in a flutter app container?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, flutter, dart, webview

I'm building a Flutter app for iOS and Android. 
I have already built the website using angular. The app and website have the same specs. (But my client *needs* an app). I'm wondering if it would be bad form to simply wrap the website in a Flutter container using the webview widget. Thoughts?

And yes, I'm aware Ionic exists. I regret not going down that path. I'm also concerned there would be a lot of refactoring of code whereas if I just use a webview, I would only make changes to the existing website.

I'm mainly worried about performance and bugs. And how about DOM errors? Would using webview in a flutter app be a practical solution?

Comment: If you find my answer good fit, please mark it as correct :D , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can work but performance and features are not that good via webview.

Why don't you try **PWA** ( progressive web application ) approach?

The pwa approach build apps that are fast, work in offline mode, have native functions but somewhat limited.

They are installable from chrome without need of having play-store but they can be uploaded to stores like google play, apple store etc.

They work on desktop, mobile platforms.

I would give a try on this approach, I've built few pwa apps and they perform awesome.

Highly recommend pwa!

Have a look on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_applications), [google](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps) and specifically for [angular](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNSa2u3xT10i5MCQEL_j48f83y7PjQ%3A1572165877755&ei=9Vi1XavcLaOurgSL04GADw&q=pwa%20angular&oq=pwa%20angular&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203l10.7451.8486..8615...0.0..0.141.947.0j8......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39j0j0i67.ctmQ1YBS2as&ved=0ahUKEwjrqq-lhrzlAhUjl4sKHYtpAPAQ4dUDCAs&uact=5).

Comment: That seems like a valid option. The only thing to giving me pause is the different implementation routes with Apple vs Google.

Comment: Ok, try it and give me a sign if you encounter some problems, you can reach me all the time , Best :D